# DBMS NORMALIZATION 2nd Normalization Form

Tags: database-normalization

Voter(voter_id, voter_name, residential_address, current_city, current_state, current_postal_code).

Postal code is unique for each city and state and each address has only one postal code.

In normalization terms, Voter is in 2nf or 3nf?

Comment: Is `voter_ID` Unique ?

Comment: I think it's 1nf because the city, state, and postal code can be extracted and you aren't referencing any other table, so it can't even be 2nf

Comment: I have to agree with @cricket_007 for clarification : http://i.imgur.com/Nz8cge9.jpg

Comment: And the rule for determining whether a relation is in 2nf is...?

Comment: @cricket_007 Highest normal form of a table has nothing to do with any other table.

Comment: @philipxy Not even indirectly? I was stating there is no reference that anything has been normalized, as you've pointed out. In my experience, when tables have been normalized, an id to another table(s) replaces some column(s) and those columns are moved to a new table

Comment: @cricket_007 Normalization does not involve the introduction of new column names that aren't names of columns of the original table. What you just described is not normalization. Normalization replaces a table with column set {c,...} by new tables whose column sets are subsets of {c,...}.

Comment: @philipxy In order to normalize you have to reorganize columns in order to reduce redundancy. That's literally the definition of database normalization. Please explain how to reorganize and extract duplicate data from a table without modifying the columns

Comment: @cricket_007 My suggestion is that you read about normalization in a textbook. (Normalization is replacing a table that is always the natural join of smaller tables by those tables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check its highest normal form, follow this basic steps:

1. First rename the attributes of "Voter" for simplicity.
   voter_id as "A"
   voter_name as "B"
   residential_address as "C"
   current_city as "D"
   current_state as "E"
   current_postal_code as "F"
2. According to given FD's : {DE -> F , C -> F }

3.Here Candidate keys are: {ABCDE}.
    hence,
          Prime attributes (5): {A,B,C,D,E} ,
          Non Prime attributes (1): {F}

For 2NF:
"Partial Dependencies are not allowed".
Means, A part of candidate key should not determine a non prime attributes.

here ,partial dependencies are : {DE -> F , C -> F }

So, this table is not in 2NF.

**To be into 2NF ,relation should be decompose like this:

R1 ={DEF},

R2 = {CF}

R3 = {ABCDE}

Hope this helps. For more detail like how to decompose a table and all, you can also refer : [Detailed explanation of Normal forms](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)

Answer (score 0):

Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. It's *not* based on column names, although that seems to be what university students are being taught based on their questions on SO.

I'd presume that "voter_id" is a surrogate key, but that's just educated guesswork. (And that's *not* a good basis for designing databases.) If it's a surrogate key, then "voter_id" is unique, so we have this FD.

- voter_id -> voter_name, residential_address, current_city, current_state, current_postal_code

You said, "Postal code is unique for each city and state . . .", so we also have this FD.

- current_city, current_state -> current_postal_code

Finally, you said, ". . . each address has only one postal code".

Based on my experience, I think it's unlikely that you meant residential_address -> current_postal_code. I think you meant that residential_address, current_city, current_state -> current_postal_code.  But we already know that current_city, current_state -> current_postal_code, so this doesn't tell us anything useful about functional dependencies.

If there are only these two functional dependencies, then the only candidate key for "voters" is "voter_id".

2NF is concerned with partial key dependencies. The *only* candidate key is a *single* column. Therefore, *partial* key dependencies can't exist. So "voters" is in 2NF.

3NF is concerned with transitive dependencies. There's at least one: voter_id -> current_city, current_state, and current_city, current_state -> current_postal_code. So "voters" is not in 3NF.